# Inheritance with MyBatis and XML

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

So I got MyBatis inheritance working with annotations - child inherited `@Select` functionality.
But with XML files it's not working accordingly.
It will throw:
`org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement /.../`

Saw that some used `extends` on the `mapper` element, but for me it says `"Attribute extends not allowed here"`

Tried `<cache/>` on parent and `<cache-ref namespace="parent"/>` on child but that threw `org.apache.ibatis.builder.IncompleteElementException: No cache for namespace 'parent'`

So how to get MyBatis inheritance working with XML configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Attribute *extends* applies to *resultMap* only.

*cache* and *cache-ref* are about cache management.

All what may look like extending is actually factorizing: define *sql* fragments in a XML mapper and reference them in other mappers. E.g:

-Mapper1.xml:

```
<sql id="a">/* dummy will never actually been included */</sql>
<sql id="b"> something common to include </sql>
<sql id="template">
    <include refid="a" />
    <include refid="Mapper1.b" />
</sql>
```

-Mapper2.xml

```
<sql id="a"> something specific to this mapper </sql>
<select id="statement">
    <include refid="Mapper1.template" />
</select>
```

*include* tag behaves just like copy/paste of referenced fragments.
Then the select statement will yield:

```
something specific to this mapper
something common to include
```

The trick is to play with prefixing or not referenced fragments. It may look like overriding.

Answer (score 0):

I agree whit balckwizzard cache and cache-ref are not useful in this case (I have read too somewhere a post that suggest to use they to extend xml but I think that the post war an error)

I have put an answer that I think is good for you too:
[Mybatis Generator: What's the best way to separate out “auto generated” and “hand edited files”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720102/mybatis-generator-whats-the-best-way-to-separate-out-auto-generated-and-han/42653576#42653576)

regards